# rails migration oddity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, migration

here is my migration:

```
  class Avatar < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  def self.up
    add_column :users,    :featured,            :boolean, :default => false, :null => false

    User.reset_column_information

    Avatar.all.each do |a|
      user = User.find(a.user_id)
      user.featured = a.featured
      user.save
    end

    drop_table :avatars
  end
```

for some reason when it runs, the featured attribute is not getting saved. if i run this from a console, it works no problem.

another strange thing i noticed is that if i make the migration fail after the column resets, and then fix it so it completes, it works when i re-run it.

when the above code runs as is for the first time, this is the log output...

```
Migrating to MoveAvatarsToProfile (20101216003815)
** ActionMailerWithRequest: initialized properly
  [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1m SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m   SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
  [1m[36mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
```

any ideas?

Comment: Rails+Ruby versions? Also, if you use the bang version (`user.save!`), any errors?

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of an end-around, but it should be much faster to run something like this:

```
User.execute("UPDATE users 
              SET users.featured = avatars.featured 
              WHERE users.id = avatars.user_id")
```

This doesn't explain the odd behavior you're seeing, but if you have a lot of users, it should prove a significantly faster (and less RAM intensive) solution.

Comment: yeah i dont have that many users, and this is only a 1 time thing to run after my migration, so i could manually do it in the console after i migrate... but its more of a learning experience for me at this point and figuring out why! i need to understand!!!